# How to pass Javascript code from a PHP file to a JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using small stock charts in metronic with the following js file to pull the data array. How can I build the loop in PHP and then with ajax dump the source into my js file? Or is there a way to loop my data from PHP in js after success?

Example:

```
a($("#m_chart_sales_by_apps_2_1"), [10, 20, -5, 8, -20, -2, -4, 15, 5, 8], mApp.getColor("danger"), 2);
```

Comment: Build whatever data you need in PHP, then `echo` it as a string to the JS. Note that the JS code will need to be placed in a .php file for it to be interpreted properly.

Comment: I tried to echo the exact code in PHP, but cannot get it to work. How do you print it in AJAX result?

Comment: as it is suggested above. echo the data in <script> tag in the <head>  `var data = <? echo $data; ?>`  .. now js will have access to `data`. You may need to json_encode or other if they are needed.

Comment: `How do you print it in AJAX result?` You `echo` it from the endpoint you called.

Comment: @Janp You shouldn't need to `parseJSON` - jquery should recognise it as json automatically and parse it for you.  Or you could use `$.ajax({ ... , dataType: "json"}).done(function(data) { console.log(data); })`; to tell jquery it's json.   Try console logging the result directly (if it's a string, then go ahead and parse it).